# Setting umask of libvirt/virt-manager for proper permissions in a directory shared by host and guest

Tags: linux, permissions, virtual-machine, umask, virt-manager

I'm attempting to create a directory that is fully available to both the host and guest systems of a virt-manager/libvirt/QEMU/KVM virtual machine, with read, write and execute permissions for non-root users of both systems. Both OSes are Debian - the host is Wheezy, the guest, Jessie. I have been mostly successful, with one exception - files created within the guest OS and the shared directory are unavilable to non-root users on the host system.

The problem that I am running into is that when creating new files within the shared directory in the guest OS, virt-manager/libvirt creates them with their permissions set to 700 (full access for owner - in this case, a user called `libvirt-qemu`, and no permissions whatsoever for any other users or groups). Essentially, this is equivalent to the libvirt-qemu user's session umask being set to 077. This makes these files inaccessible to the host's non-root users.

The solution that I am trying to implement is to have both the `libvirt-qemu` user and the relevant other users on the host OS all belong to an additional new, secondary user group called `vmshares`, and have the shared directory owned by the `vmshares` group, with the SGID bit set to have all of its contents to also be owned by `vmshares` - which should accomplish what I want. However, I cannot seem to get virt-manager to create new files within the host shared directory with any umask except 077, when I need it to be using 007, so that these files also grant full permissions to members of the `vmshares` group.

I have tried creating a new file, /etc/pam.d/libvirt with the following contents, to implement the umask policy for the libvirt-qemu user:

`libvirtd session requisite pam_umask.so umask=0007`

I have also attempted to create a `.profile` file in /var/lib/libvirt/ with just the following line:

`umask 007`

I have also tried adding that line near the top of the libvirt-bin init script in /etc/init.d/libvirt-bin.

virt-manager/libvirt seems to ignore all of these completely.

Please, how can I accomplish my goal of having a fully usable shared directory on both the host and guest systems?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old post but I just recently solved this exact problem by submitting patches to libvirt.  [Starting in libvirt v6.10](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/commit/ae110dc58b4dd09472b1ad8272652d6f8a031c45?view=inline), you'll be able to specify the "fmode" and "dmode" options on 9pfs shares which control the default host permissions on files and directories, respectively.

If you can't run v6.10, I found a workaround using the `qemu:commandline` feature of libvirt's XML domain to pass the raw QEMU flags. I wrote [a blog post](https://www.turek.dev/posts/set-libvirt-qemu-9pfs-umask-using-fmode-dmode/) about how to do this but the quick version is to put something like

```xml
<commandline xmlns="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
  <arg value="-fsdev"/>
  <arg value="local,security_model=mapped,id=fsdev-fs0,path=/path/to/share,fmode=0644,dmode=0755"/>
  <arg value="-device"/>
  <arg value="virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=sharename,bus=pci.6,addr=0x0"/>
</commandline>
```

into your domain XML as a child of "domain."  The blog post goes into more detail about the values but you may need to tweak `fsdev-fs0`, `fs0`, and `sharename` to fit your domain.